# ProxyPassReverse & URLs rewrite: same configuration, different behaviours

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

What I'm trying to do is pretty common: expose internal lan webisite on the internet through an apache server using ProxyPass.

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://192.168.2.125/
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://192.168.2.125/

ProxyPass /app2/ http://192.168.2.1/
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://192.168.2.1/
```

App1 works like a charm rewriting all the urls in every page.
App2 instead doesn't rewrite the urls correctly (i.e. the browser shows server.com/login instead of the correct server.com/app2/login).
I really don't understand why I have different behaviours using the same configuration. I also tried using the rewrite engine with no luck.
I can't modify the apps, I just have to proxy them.

Comment: I'm assuming they don't both proxy to the same app? If app2 does not return relative URLs that will explain the behaviour

Comment: and relative url are used